# meaning code at comment part from mysqldump result

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump

on the results from mysqldump i got this part from create procedure before line `BEGIN`

```
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spPayrollProcess` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = latin1 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = latin1 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = latin1_swedish_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
```

what mean of part `!50003` ?
where i can see meaning of this code ?

Comment: This means that the code will be executed if server version is 5.00.03 or above and ignored otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [executable comment syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/) that allows the same sql to be imported into a mysql-5.0.2 or earlier server that doesn't understand the `SET` modes.